# ChartJS: Can interior of polar area chart be hollow?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a polar bar chart made with chart.js and it looks something like this.

[image]

But I would like to have a hollow center (where the bars do not extend all the way to the center of the circle) and the documentation seems silent on this. It's possible the functionality doesn't exist but I'll ask anyways. I'd like a chart that looks more like this.

[image]

Know what I mean?

Answer (score 0):

I what you are looking for is called an Aster Plot. They look like this:
[two aster plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4J6lM.jpg)

Here is one implementation:

http://bl.ocks.org/bbest/2de0e25d4840c68f2db1